# Anchor before table row

Tags: php, html

I'm dynamically generating my code in *PHP* and adding the **ID** atribut from database to the anchor href. It looks like this :

**PHP**

```
<table>
<tr><th>ID</th></tr>
<?php
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM table;")) {

    $stmt->execute();                   
    $stmt->bind_result($id);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<a href="somepage.php?id='.$id.'"><tr>...</tr></a>'
    }

    .... //closing the statment + error
?>
</table>
```

Which generated this **HTML**:

```
<a href="somepage.php?id=1></a>
<a href="somepage.php?id=2></a>
<a href="somepage.php?id=3></a>
<a href="somepage.php?id=4></a>
....
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
<tr>....</tr>
....
```

Why isn't the `<tr>...</tr>` inside the `<a>` and why it isn't clickable?

I tried adding some style to the `<a>` (`display,width,height`) but with no luck.

How to fix this?

Comment: just a wild guess, but i think that <table> can contain only a specific set of elements, and "<a>" is not one of them?

Comment: @STTLCU I tought it has to do something with that. But even if I put the `<a>` inside the `<tr>` , it shows the same problem. But if I put in the `<td>`, then it works. But I need to have the whole row clickable. What are my options ? With JS ?

Comment: The `<a>` tag cannot contain block level elements like `<table>`.

Comment: @Rikesh, actually in html5 it can.

Comment: @STTLCU - agree with you, but here it seems OP is not using HTML5.

Comment: why not? i don't see anything imposing html401 here

Comment: @Rikesh I'm using HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the link as ID in your table row, like:

```
<table>
    <tr id='http://www.google.com/'>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

use this little jquery script to detect the clicked row/link

```
$('tr').click(function () {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Used class instead of ID. Works . Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Markup that has `tr` inside `a` is invalid, and all bets are off. You cannot make a `tr` as such a link in HTML, though you could use JavaScript to associate an `onclick` handler with it. In pure HTML, you would have to make the content of each cell separately a link, `<td><a href=...>...</a></td>`.

Comment: Then how to select the clicked row with JS/JQuery ? For example, if I click on row1 then it will redirect me to row1? The selector is the problem.